# c++ vector operator[] reference

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);
map<int, vector<int> >hash;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);
vec.push_back(4);

hash[-1] = vec;
vector<int> ref = hash[-1];
ref.push_back(5);
cout <<hash[-1].back() <<endl;  // prints 4
hash[-1].push_back(6);
cout <<hash[-1].back() <<endl;  // prints 6
```

I'm not sure, why in the code above, hash[-1].back() doesn't print 5 (output is 4).
[] operator of vector returns a reference and since I'm adding 5 to the reference, shouldn't it affect hash[-1] ? or is a copy being made how does the last push statement works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a reference which you then make a copy of with

```
vector<int> ref = hash[-1];
```

Did you mean

```
vector<int>& ref = hash[-1];
```

Comment: Ah, failed to notice that I missed a &. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
vector<int> ref = hash[-1];
```

you are creating a new `vector<int>` called `ref` that is initialized with the copy constructor to `hash[-1]`.

What you really want is to use a reference:

```
vector<int>& ref = hash[-1];
```